# Iterating over Google Cloud Storage Objects in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, multiprocessing, google-cloud-storage, opencv

I have around 40,000 images in a cloud storage bucket and I need to retrieve them using Python in order to make a video out of the images. Currently I'm using a for loop in Python and its taking 2-3 hours for 40k images. How can I use multi-processing to speed this up?

Current Pseudo Code:

```
import cv2
from google.cloud import storage

frameSize = (1920, 1080)
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = "name-of-my-bucket"
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_video.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG'), 2, frameSize, True)

blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

for blob in blobs:
    image_string = blob.download_as_text()

    # Pre-processing the base64 string
    image_string = image_string.split(",", 1)[1]

    # Decoding base64 string
    nparr = np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(image_string), np.uint8)

    image = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    image = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_180)

    # Writing image to VideoWriter
    out.write(image)


out.release()
```

Comment: I doubt that the library cv2 supports creating a video using parallel tasks.

Comment: Yes, the images will still need to be in a sequence and doing that in parallel would tedious. However, the bottleneck is the retrieval from the GCP bucket which could be done in parallel.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/jksqlm/is_it_possible_to_use_python_multiprocessing_with/

This thread on reddit is related but could not find any guidance on how to go about implementing it.

Comment: You can download objects in parallel. Then you need to serialize feeding them to cv2. Once you have written code that has a problem, create a question.

Comment: Noted, will do that. Could you point me to a rough direction on how I should go about downloading them in parallel?

Comment: I would start by reading the Google Cloud Storage API documentation.

Comment: [`multiprocessing.imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) might be a good place to start looking.  e.g. this would let you download and decode several images in parallel, which could then be fed serially/in-order to `cv2` for writing into the video file

Comment: Ok will check it out, thanks!